# TinyMCE in ASP.net - how can i extract out the html?

Tags: asp.net, html, tinymce

i am trying to create an ASP.net site where a user can have a wysiwyg editor and can put together a page and i am then saving that page (the html) as an html page.

I have looked at all the examples but it seems that from my testing, after i post to the server, i can get the content in pure text form but i can't seems to determine where to get the actual html equivalent.

suggestions?

Comment: Hey ! Don't degrade your own question... It's counter-productive, and there is no dumb question. ( ok, some are... but not this one. )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `name` attribute of the `textarea` will be the POST parameter key.

```
Dim Html As String = Request.Form("txtBody")
```